Hyphenation without apostrophe and compound words
I'm French, and in the French language, we often use apostrophes at the beginning of words, like in "l'action." The problem is that Indesign treats the apostrophe as a letter, so with hyphenation set to a minimum of 4 letters, it splits the word like this: "l'ac-tion." This looks really bad since the word is cut right after the second letter.
The second issue is with compound words, like "coffre-fort." These should not be hyphenated at all because they already contain a hyphen, but it sometimes happens anyway, like this: "cof-fre-fort."
Is there a way to further refine hyphenation settings beyond just the minimum number of letters?
Thanks in advance, and sorry if my English isn’t perfect—it’s not my mother tongue! :)

Discretionary Hyphens should help with both issues.  A discretionary hyphen is not visible unless the word needs to be broken at the end of a line. (I'm using - as a representation of the discretionary hyphen.) To insert a discretionary hyphen:

Choose Type > Insert Special Character > Hyphens And Dashes > Discretionary Hyphen

Or press Ctrl+Shift+- (Windows) or Command+Shift+- (Mac OS) to
insert a discretionary hyphen.


To prevent words beginning with l' from hyphenating, place a discretionary hyphen at the beginning of the word. The hyphen will be invisible and the word won't break.
-l'action
If you want to allow longer words starting with l' to hyphenate, like l'agglomération, you can set a discretionary hyphen where you want to allow the word to break. The hyphens will be invisible unless the word breaks:

l'aggloméra-tion
or l'agglomé-ration
or l'agglo-mération

To prevent compound words from hyphenating, place a discretionary hyphen at the beginning of the word, and a regular hyphen to separate the parts:
-coffre-fort.
For really special circumstances, like y a-t-il, place a non-breaking hyphen before the "y" and insert a non-breaking space (Ctrl+Shift+X [Windows] or Command+Shift+X [Mac OS]) between "y" and "a":
-y a-t-il will then be kept intact.
Adobe has detailed instructions on how to customize hyphenation and justification.

Oh, thanks for this detailed answer! =D
But it’s my fault—I should have phrased it this way: I’m looking for a way to automate this behavior. I was already aware of the Discretionary Hyphen and forcing the word to switch lines with Shift + Enter, for example, but these are all manual corrections and can be overlooked by mistake if not flagged.
My question is about settings to change the behavior of automatic hyphenation in these specific cases, if any exist.

Is your document set to French language? In the Character panel, choose the appropriate dictionary in the Language menu
